# Adwords API, OAuth2 and service account in Java

Tags: java, google-ads-api

I have switched to the OAuth2 authentification for accessing the Adwords API. I want to use service account, because our application does not have user interaction. Therefore I created a service account in the Google APIs console for the mcc account. And used:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
.setTransport(new NetHttpTransport())
.setJsonFactory(new JacksonFactory())
.setServiceAccountId("..@developer.gserviceaccount.com")
.setServiceAccountScopes("https://adwords.google.com/api/adwords/")
.setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(file)
.setServiceAccountUser("<MCC Account Email")
.build();
```

to create the credentials.

When I now try to make an API call or just call `credential.refreshToken()`, I get :

```
com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException: 400 Bad Request
{
  "error" : "access_denied"
}
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenResponseException.from(TokenResponseException.java:105)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.executeUnparsed(TokenRequest.java:303)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.TokenRequest.execute(TokenRequest.java:323)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.executeRefreshToken(GoogleCredential.java:345)
at com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential.refreshToken(Credential.java:526)
```

..

Can anyone tell me, what I am doing  wrong or what I have missed doing?

Answer (score 0):

Can`t say from piece code you posted, i am using exactly same way in my app and everything works fine.

My jar versions are :

```
 google-api-services-oauth2-v2-rev9-1.7.2-beta.jar
 google-http-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
 google-oauth-client-1.12.0-beta.jar
```

if you are out of ideas try to change version of oauth2 library.

Comment: Which adwords Api do you use? I use:   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
      <artifactId>ads-lib</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-ads</groupId>
      <artifactId>adwords-axis</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-http-client-jackson2</artifactId>
      <version>1.14.1-beta</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: I am not using adwords API. Try to load some other informations e.g. user contacts or google drive document to check if it`s specific adwords issue or authentification issue for all APIs.